# LINQ list property to array?

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

What's the best way to do this where `PROPNAME` could be any property of type `T`?  Build it up with reflection, or is there a good LINQ way of doing this?

```
T[] vals = people.Select(x => x.PROPNAME).ToArray<T>();
```

this is the best I've got so far:

```
    public T[] ConvertListCol<TFrom,T>(IEnumerable<TFrom> list, string col)
    {
        var typ = typeof (TFrom);
        var props = typ.GetProperties();
        var prop = (from p in props where p.Name == col select p).FirstOrDefault();
        var ret = from o in list select prop.GetValue(o, null);
        return ret.ToArray<T>();
    }
```

Got an error in the return... but getting closer.  It's okay, but a little messier than I'd hoped.

Comment: Are you after an array of the property names of `people`?

Comment: Are you trying to make a reusable piece of code where you could specify any property and get back the set of string representations?

Comment: situation is that there's a large poco object of many properties, and an API would like to see them one column at a time rather than one row at a time.

Comment: When is Propname known : design time, compile time, run time?

Comment: propname is known at compile time, however, I'm faced with a switch statement of n LINQ statements, or something based off reflection.  Hoping for something a little smarter effiency & elegance wise.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Using a non-explicit var type, it will automatically generate the type for you

```
var names = people.Select(x => x.PROPNAME).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 9):

The type will be inferred if you use the var keyword:

```
var names = people.Select(x => x.PROPNAME).ToArray();
```

Comment: there is no dynamic way to rename a PROPNAME based on a string.  See the new info "prop.GetValue(" that I put there in a recent edit.  That's one answer, however, it's not really that efficient.